# Maximum Harddrive size for Storage Spaces?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-10, raid, storage-spaces

I'm attempting to set up a software RAID1 of 2*8TB drives and after encountering the incredibly slow syncing of Windows' mirroring system (both drives are empty) in disk management I looked around and found Storage Spaces.

They seem great, especially when combined with ReFS for data security, however my attempts are failing at creating the storage space with the 8TB drives. My 2TB drive works fine but I can not add my 8TB drives.

Attached some images that might be of help.

[image: Disk Management]

[image: Storage Space Creation Attempt]

Hope someone can point me in the right direction, can't find any information as to why this shouldn't work.

Kind regards.

EDIT: Adding nicely formatted output of Get-PhysicalDisk

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-PhysicalDisk | ft FriendlyName, UniqueId -auto

FriendlyName         UniqueId
------------         --------
WDC WD20EFRX-68AX9N0 {4d4b3dd5-ff79-b54d-0b87-0100a3693c37}
INTEL SSDSC2BW120A4  {4d66a2c5-77f9-9346-919a-db8a23713050}
WDC WD20EFRX-68AX9N0 {b75e5e0c-0cf9-b454-aa9a-d4751b92821f}
WDC WD80EFZX-68UW8N0 {c57323a1-8798-e4c2-993a-9d43a88b1831}
WDC WD80EFZX-68UW8N0 {dbabd8d1-6444-e528-9d87-fe2ef46091fb}
```

Comment: What settings on the storage pool did you select?

Comment: There's no settings to be chosen; Open storage space manager -> Create new storage pool (none made before) -> UAC prompt -> Shows my unassigned HDDs -> The error you see.

Comment: I must warn you: I’ve experienced ReFS fail in strange ways. Because it’s so awesome, there are no official recovery tools available. A reboot solved it, but it almost gave me a heart attack. Do not use ReFS.

Comment: Execute the following command in PowerShell and provide the output: `Get-PhysicalDisk | ft FriendlyName, UniqueId -auto`. Also, what controller are the disks connected to?

Comment: Ok, I wasn't set on ReFS and after reading into it more I'll wait until Server 2016 gets released with (probably) an updated version that'll trickle down to Windows Pro as well. 


`FriendlyName         UniqueId
------------         --------
WDC WD20EFRX-68AX9N0 {4d4b3dd5-ff79-b54d-0b87-0100a3693c37}
INTEL SSDSC2BW120A4  {4d66a2c5-77f9-9346-919a-db8a23713050}
WDC WD20EFRX-68AX9N0 {b75e5e0c-0cf9-b454-aa9a-d4751b92821f}
WDC WD80EFZX-68UW8N0 {c57323a1-8798-e4c2-993a-9d43a88b1831}
WDC WD80EFZX-68UW8N0 {dbabd8d1-6444-e528-9d87-fe2ef46091fb}`

Comment: They are all connected to my Motherboards S-ATA AHCI controller. All via SATA III as well.

Comment: Hm so they do have unique unique IDs. That’s not it, then.

Comment: Same error happens even if I only choose one of the 8TB drives, whereas it's entirely possible with the one 2TB drive by itself.

Comment: So I tried this with two 8TB VHD, and it works. I do not understand what is happening...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after playing around with VHDs and finding out it works perfectly fine with 2*8TB VHDs, I proceeded to add my two physical 8TB drives to the storage space containing the 2 VHDs and that worked.

After I decided to try my luck and after removing the VHDs and the storage space tried only my two 8TB WD HDDs and lo and behold, it worked without a problem.

Thanks for the help guys but it seems it just fixed itself somehow.